# [next-auth]: `useSession` must be wrapped in a <SessionProvider /> error on the existing js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am adding the following code to my existing js file to validate the authentication and I am trying to follow the next-auth documentations but I am getting this error "[next-auth]: `useSession` must be wrapped in a SessionProvider"

I am using github credentials for the validations

**my code:** Working when browsing to the localhost:3000/auth/api/signin

[...nextauth.js]

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GitHubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github'
export default NextAuth({
    providers:[
        GitHubProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
})
```

I want to put the authentication to my code written in the abc/index.js

**This is my code with the next-auth** and this throwing this error "[next-auth]: `useSession` must be wrapped in a SessionProvider"

localhost:3000/abc/index.js

```
import React, { Component, useMemo, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSession, SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) { // i have added it here since I am not using _app.js file
  return (
    <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}
const abc = ({ json }) => {
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  if (session) {
    return (
      <>
        Signed in as {session.user.email} <br />
        <button onClick={() => signOut()}>Sign out</button>
      </>
    );
  }
  return (
    <>
      Not signed in <br />
      <button onClick={() => signIn()}>Sign in</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: it is late to say but anyway... the _app.js isn't bad at all. 99 percent of the projects have it. it has NOT any problem or downside having the _app.js in your app. so, go for it :)

Answer (score 14):

Make sure to wrap your app with the `SessionProvider` component in the `_app.js` file:

```
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
      <SessionProvider session={pageProps.session}>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </SessionProvider>
    );
  }

export default MyApp;
```

More [info about `_app.js` in the Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app).

Comment: my app doesnt have the _app.js. Can this be done without the _app.js?

Comment: I am now seeing this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'session' of undefined

Comment: follow this tutorial. https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes. /pages/_app.js provider need to add with session.

Comment: @orbnexus, you can add this in your layout.

Answer (score 9):

I had similar problem when updating to Next.js 13, solution i found:

- "use client" providers extracted to separate files,
- layout.tsx that wraps children components with providers,
- all pages.tsx that are used within that layout have to be a server component (without "use client")

In main layout.tsx i use Redux and NextAuth providers:

```js
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <NextAuthProvider>
          <ReduxProviders>
            {children}
          </ReduxProviders>
        </NextAuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Next-Auth provider:

```js
"use client";

import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

type Props = {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
};

export const NextAuthProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
};
```

Redux provider:

```js
"use client";

import store from "./store";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

export function ReduxProviders({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution!**

In next.js v13, I used the `{ SessionProvider }`  structure by wrapping it in the main layout structure.

**layout.tsx:**

```
'use client'
import '@/styles/global.css'
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';
import { Session } from 'next-auth'

interface Props {
  session: Session | null
  children: React.ReactNode
}

 const RootLayout: React.FC <Props> = ({ children, session } ) => {
  return (
    <html lang="tr">

      <head />
      <body>
        {/* SessionProvider ile sarmallarız ki tüm route lara erişebilelim diye / yukarıda "use client" tanımlamayı unutma! */}
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
          {children}
        </SessionProvider>        
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

export default RootLayout
```

**The error I got:**

```
error node_modules\next-auth\react\index.js (119:0) @ useSession
- error Error: [next-auth]: `useSession` must be wrapped in a <SessionProvider/>
```

**Solution Way:** Then I decided to move the "**SessionProvider**" structure into the main page.tsx in the app folder.

**page.tsx:**

```
'use client'
import HomeContainer from "@/containers/home/index";
import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';
import { Session } from 'next-auth'

interface Props {
  session: Session | null
}

const Home: React.FC<Props> = ({ session } ) => {
  return (
    <>
    {/* SessionProvider ile sarmallarız ki tüm route lara erişebilelim diye / yukarıda "use client" tanımlamayı unutma! */}
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <HomeContainer />
    </SessionProvider>
    </>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

**And so I solved the error.**

**The final version of the layout page is below:**

```
import '@/styles/global.css'
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

 const RootLayout: React.FC <Props> = ({ children } ) => {
  return (
    
    <html lang="tr">

      <head />
      <body>
          {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}

export default RootLayout
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be late for this but i'm gonna post this if it might be useful.

in next.js 13.4 create a layout.js file inside the route where the session is being used and wrap `SessionProvider` to it. it works for me.

`app/posts/createPost/layout.js`

```
"use client";
import { SessionProvider } from "next-auth/react";

export default function PostLayout({
  children, // will be a page or nested layout
}) {
  return <SessionProvider>{children}</SessionProvider>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My silly mistake was that instead of passing pageProps.session to SessionProvider, i was doing this in App component:

```
    const { data: session, status } = useSession();
    
     <SessionProvider session={session}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </SessionProvider>
```

Then i removed the useSession hook from app.tsx and and instead used the hook in child components. Finally, passed pageProps.session to SessionProvider like this:

Note: pageProps is passed to App component by Next.js

```
<SessionProvider session={pageprops.session}>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </SessionProvider>
```